# Renewal of Letsencrypt cert looks fine but certificate on the page won't update

Tags: ubuntu, lets-encrypt, linode

Everything looks correct, I renew the certificate but when I go to the website the security certificate doesn't update.

Here is the message after renewing the cert
[image]

I have restarted the server

```
systemctl start apache2.service
systemctl stop apache2.service
systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Am I missing a step somewhere, normally they always updated fine.

I though it could be a time lag but it's been a couple of days but they still haven't updated.

Running Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all the SSL certs on the server www.domain.com-le-ssl.conf

Removed all certbot files:

https://medium.com/@mhagemann/correct-way-to-delete-a-certbot-ssl-certificate-e8ee123e6e01

command: `$ sudo certbot delete`

Installed Certbot again, which had its complications as the dkp package could not be found so I updated the repository to point to python3.7

Then followed the install of certbot again
https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-apache

And as there was no www.domain.com-le-ssl.conf there it created new ones that then connected to the web domains.
There cerbot ran successfully and all of the web domains updated.